# Ad accountexpires setting issue

Tags: c#, active-directory, azure-active-directory, utc, filetime

This code in a console program works fine

```
DateTime enteredDate = DateTime.Parse("2/2/2019 1:16:47 PM");
//change the time to 6pm
enteredDate = enteredDate.Date.Add(new TimeSpan(18, 00, 0));
Debug.WriteLine($"Entered date : {enteredDate}");
Debug.WriteLine($"FromFileTime: DateTime.FromFileTime(enteredDate.ToFileTime())}");
```

output is

```
Entered date : 2/2/2019 6:00:00 PM
FromFileTime: 2/2/2019 6:00:00 PM
```

When i set this time for an AD attribute like this

```
directoryEntry.Properties["accountExpires"].Value = Convert.ToString(enteredDate .ToFileTime());
```

it is writing the time part as 12:00:00 PM instead of 6pm. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is a time zone issue and you are in a UTC+6 time zone.

I don't think you have a problem at all. The [`accountExpires`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adschema/a-accountexpires) attribute stores the time as a number that "represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC)". That's exactly what [`ToFileTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tofiletime) does for you. You're doing it right.

But note that it is stored in UTC. If you are seeing it as 12:00 PM, that's probably because you are reading it as UTC time.

6:00 PM your time is 12:00 PM UTC